# Compress images in azure blob with ImageMagick

Tags: c#, .net, azure, imagemagick, azure-functions

I'm writing an azure function to compress images uploaded to a blob storage and save the compressed image to another blob. I use [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET) nuget package for this.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run(
        [BlobTrigger("test/{name}", Connection = "")]Stream image,
        [Blob("test-output/{name}", FileAccess.ReadWrite)]CloudBlockBlob output,
        string name,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {image.Length} Bytes");
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            ImageOptimizer imageOptimizer = new ImageOptimizer();
            imageOptimizer.Compress(memoryStream);
            output.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
        }
    }
```

But the following line throws an exception,

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the copy, you need to rewind the `MemoryStream`

```
image.CopyTo(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

otherwise, the position will be at the end of the data and any read operations on it will return 0 data.